# Is there an example for using NdkBinder with CMakeLists.txt

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-binder

I found some information on Android Dev Site,  https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/ndk-binder, but don't know how to implement this.

Another piece of information is the test at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/libs/binder/ndk/tests?autodive=0/.

In the test at googlesource.com, they are using libs such as `libbase` and `libutils`, but I failed to include them in CmakeLists.txt by using `find_library(base-lib base)` and `find_library(utils-lib utils)`.

My Dev Env:

buildToolsVersion "30.0.2",
ndkVersion '21.2.6472646',
c++17

Comment: Using it to do what?

Comment: @DanAlbert Just trying to do communication between two native processes, and I don't want to use Java to implement onBind(). I am trying to do this with unix domain sockets now, but encountering a policy issue. https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1469

Comment: @DanAlbert  I create a GLES layer(with functionality like renderdoc), and applications can load the .so I built, then the GLES layer can monitor the use of EGL/GLES functions, but I didn't found an efficient way to expose the data I collected to another app. renderdoc is simply using TCP socket on localhost, but I think UDS or NdkBinder is more suitable for this use case.

Comment: @JinesiYelizati Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @Flot2011 No...I used HTTP port to communicate between two apps.